# Reading/writing to screen process in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gnu-screen

I was wondering how one might connect to a screen process in C/C++, I often want to have a C program listen to the output to that screen window and react to that output as well as send some input to the program running on that session. I am just unsure as to how I'm supposed to connect to that screen session and I haven't found anything very useful doing my searches.

Comment: Is it fair game to attach your program between `screen` and the client on that window? Or do you really want to _attach_ after `screen` has started that client?

Comment: I'd like to be able to attach after screen has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want is involved.  screen expects to be running inside a terminal device, so if (I'm assuming you are on linux) you want to create it programatically you have to set up a terminal pseudodevice using `posix_openpt()`, set up the slave device with `grantpt()/unlockpt()`, forking, opening the slave pty in the child process, duping it to stdin/out/err, and finally exec'ing screen with the appropriate options.  Now you can send commmands and receive terminal notifications as if you were a terminal emulator.  Check the man page for `pty(7)` for more details; I'm quite sure I've missed some.

Which is all a huge mess, and almost certainly overcomplicated for what you are trying to do.  So: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a server for a game that I want to read from and write to, since it accepts from stdin while the server is running to execute server commands. So basically I need to be able to read from the stdout of the server thats running and also be able to send messages to the stdin of that server.

Comment: Shouldn't your "server" be a an actual "server" instead of a console program that runs on standard I/O? Does it not take network input? This sounds like you're trying to use screen to daemonize something that isn't itself a background program.  There are better solutions there, too.

Comment: It is an actual server, like I said its a game server, so when people type in the chat it outputs that to console and you can input special server commands directly from the console as well, to say, send server messages in the chat to the game world